# How to define a new PSTricks object that is not a redefinition of a built-in PSTricks object?

Tags: pstricks

## Scenario

I want to create a new PSTricks object, e.g., `\myBatLogo[<key-val options>]{}{}...{}` that is not a redefinition of a built-in PSTricks object.

It means that any redefinition as follows does not make sense in my scenario.

```
\newpsobject{myBatLogo}{<built-in PSTrick object>}
```

## Question

How to define a new PSTrick object that is not a redefinition of a built-in PSTricks object? It must accept key-value optional arguments and mandatory arguments.

Comment: a curve, an area, or something special?

Comment: @Herbert: for simplicity, let the new object just draw BATMAN logo with `fillcolor` as an optional argument and the center bounding box position `{x,y}` as the mandatory argument.

Comment: I have no idea about PSTricks, but can't you simply define a macro (maybe using keyval for the optional arguments) that expands to the code to draw the object using built-in PSTrick objects?

Comment: @Juan: It is possible but I want to use the mechanism the PSTricks authors use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\makeatletter
\def\psBatman{\pst@object{psBatman}}
\def\psBatman@i(#1)#2{%
  \begin@ClosedObj%
  \rput(#1){\psframebox{#2}}
  \end@ClosedObj%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pspicture(7,7)
\psBatman(1,1){Batman}
\psBatman[fillcolor=red!50,shadow=true,framesep=20pt,framearc=0.3](3,4){\Huge Me}
\psBatman*[linecolor=blue!20,framesep=20pt](6,6){\huge you}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a counterpart of `\begin@ClosedObj` ? Is it `\begin@OpenObj` ?

Comment: @xport: yes, that one can have line ends like arrows. And we have `\begin@SpecialObj` for special purposes.

Comment: Is there a free documentation on the web explaining how to use these macros?

Comment: @xport: sure http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf. pp 163 for high level objects (without using PostScript code) and pp 171 for low level objects (coordinate transformation and using PostScript code).